# pros and cons for using a service like redistogo.com?

Tags: database, node.js, redis

We use redis to store 'active' information that we need to recall quickly. Do you lose the benefits of redis's speed by using something like redis to go?

What are the pros and cons to services like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The further your packets have to hop to get from application to database, the more latency you introduce.  In most applications and networks, you will also reduce throughput.

In your case, the latency will be the issue (many other people might object to the throughput more).  For many real-time computing applications, the network location of your various pieces matter quite a bit.  We regularly move boxes to be in the same physical datacenter and on the same physical switch as others to maximize throughput and minimize latency.

Long story short, you would surely see better performance if you had an equivalent Redis installation closer than wherever Redis To Go's hosting is located, preferably in the same datacenter as your application. However, if you're not running your own datacenter and you're not interested in managing your own machines, a hosted Redis instance is better than no Redis instance at all, right?